# How to export in the Collada dae format using the Assimp?

Tags: c++, collada, assimp

I can't get how to use `Exporter` to export my scene in `dae` format. Now, I am doing it so:

```
void Model::save(const std::string &path)
{
    // Create a new scene
    aiScene scene;
    scene.mRootNode = new aiNode();
    // Create a material
    scene.mMaterials = new aiMaterial *[1];
    scene.mMaterials[0] = new aiMaterial();
    scene.mNumMaterials = 1;
    // Create a mesh
    scene.mMeshes = new aiMesh *[_meshes.size()];
    scene.mNumMeshes = _meshes.size();
    // Set our mesh to the root node
    scene.mRootNode->mMeshes = new unsigned[_meshes.size()];
    scene.mRootNode->mNumMeshes = _meshes.size();
    // Build meshes
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < scene.mNumMeshes; ++i) {
        auto mesh = scene.mMeshes[i] = new aiMesh();
        // Set our material
        scene.mMeshes[i]->mMaterialIndex = 0;
        scene.mRootNode->mMeshes[i] = i;
        buildAiMesh(_meshes[i], mesh);
    }
    // Export to file
    Assimp::Exporter exporter;
    auto format = exporter.GetExportFormatDescription(0);
    exporter.Export(&scene, format->id, path);
}
```

I am sure it's not right but I can't find any clean documentation how to do it.

**UPDATED:**
The solution was very simple... I was needed to specify a format directly:
`exporter.Export(&scene, "collada", path);`

Comment: Looks right. What error/behavior do you get? What does `buildAiMesh` do?

Comment: @MaxVollmer, it doesn't matter in my case. I found a solution already,

Comment: Please don't add an answer as edit to your question, add an answer instead. Preferably add an explanation as to why `format->id` wasn't `"collada"` in your case (it should be when using vanilla Assimp).

Comment: The right answer. I guess we have to document this much more detailed.